# Flutter to read from a Mysql DB

Tags: php, laravel, react-native, flutter

I'm about to complete a website in Laravel and currently planning to build a mobile App as well "on both Andriod & IOS".
I was analyzing the easiest/fastest way to build an app, and now I'm trying to choose between Flutter and React, although it seems that Flutter is a winner.
In the beginning, the App will mainly read data from a Mysql DB, and in the near future I will start adding the other Create, Update, Delete features one after another in the APP.
Am I making the right decision with Flutter?

Answer (score 0):

So if your database done, then you have to only create Apis for your Curd Operation(insert, update delete, create), then just call them as you need.

The following link is the best example that will suit your question.

https://medium.com/@santosenoque.ss/how-to-connect-flutter-app-to-mysql-web-server-and-phpmyadmin-e100f47bfb82